# How can I return the current object as a JSON string from inside the object with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, oop

I need a function to return the current instance as a json text, because I will send the values with an ajax request to server side script.

I don't know where to use the "this" keyword in a jquery selector

```
function Actor(){
 this.input=function(pname,ppassword){
  this.name=pname;
  this.password=ppassword;
 }
  //I need a function to return the current instance as a json text here
  //I will send the values with an ajax request to server side script with a function 
 }
```

**I've found out that jquery doesn't support encoding as JSON and I need to use JSON2.js for serializing as JSON string.**

*New browsers have native JSON support so you can use JSON.stringify without including JSON2.js*

Comment: *"I don't know where to use the "this" keyword in a jquery selector"* How is this related to your question? How is a jQuery selector related to an `Actor` instance?

Comment: I still don't get it. Nothing in the code you provided is related to jQuery.

Comment: I give up, you really should explain your problem better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to be more specific in your question but if you need this in the input function to be a JSON string, you can use:

```
function Actor(){
    this.input=function(pname,ppassword){
       this.name=pname;
       this.password=ppassword;
       return JSON.stringify(this);//this will return pname and ppassword in json object string
     }
}
```

See here for JSON libraries for older browsers that don't support JSON object natively: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js